# NavBar Bootstrap 4, how not to hide some items in mobile screens without duplication?

Tags: html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

As in Bootstrap 4 navbar, not to hide some points with the adapter? That is, with a width of 1200px, you need to hide all but two points, without duplication. How can this be done?

I found an example of how this should work, but I don't understand how you can do it with Bootstrap.

**Example https://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/y0ypz38w**

**Code Navbar Bootstrap 4**

```html
<!-- CSS only -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- JS, Popper.js, and jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar w/ text</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarText" aria-controls="navbarText" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Leave </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Leave </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: You can use the Display property for that. 
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/

Whenever you want something to be hidden on lets say mobile, you just add the class on it.

Comment: `d-block` no help

Comment: You need to use not only d-block, for example to hide them on sm (which is like mobile devices), you need to use ```d-none d-sm-block```

Comment: Which elements do you want to stay visible when the navbar is collapsed?

Comment: @Tiramonium In the code that I have attached, there is a word `Leave' in the adapter and the rest should be hidden. https://codepen.io/moiseev1788/pen/eYZvxbG

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display` property for that on items as `d-none` etc, if you want to hide let's say "Home" item on small screen you can use something like this:

```html
<li class="nav-item active d-block d-sm-none">
  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
</li>
```

here `d-block` will be applicable on all screen sizes, and when you will hit small size then `d-sm-none` will work and it will hide your `nav-item`.

Comment: Tried your solution, it does not work. Here is the code for codepen https://codepen.io/moiseev1788/pen/eYZvxbG

Comment: try class= 'd-md-block d-sm-none' what this will do is that it will remain visible on medium to larger and to extra larger screens and will get hidden on small screens. Hope this helps.

Comment: 'd-md-block' means that the item will start displaying once it hits the "medium" screen size and it will be displayed till "extra large screen sizes"

Answer (score 0):

`class="d-none d-sm-block"`

You can change the sm to the required breakpoint. This will make it visible for everything wider than that breakpoint

Answer (score 0):

You should use `d-block d-md-none` on your `<li>`, if you want it to be hidden on Tablet size or lesser. You can also change it to whatever you want, just swap the md out and use something else. Heres a list of what you can use: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/#hiding-elements

To hide "Leave" on tablet size, you just need to add `d-block d-md-none` on your `<li>`

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar w/ text</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarText" aria-controls="navbarText" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item d-none d-md-block">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Leave</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item"">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

To do what you want you'll have to insert these links on your `navbar-brand`.

This likely won't look neat, but could provide you what you want to do.

Also, you might want to reconsider leaving 3 links visible when the navbar is collapsed. Maybe leave up to 2 visible on the small `(sm)` breakpoint (420px) and up to 3 on the medium `(md)` one (768px)

EDIT: Thinking of a less atrociously roundabout way of doing this, you could just make 3 `navbar-brand` links instead of just 1, then set the third to show only at the breakpoint where it doesn't break the layout, be it at the small or medium one.

```html
<!-- CSS only -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- JS, Popper.js, and jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    Navbar brand
  </a>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    Leave #1
  </a>
  <a class="navbar-brand d-none d-md-inline" href="#">
    Leave #2
  </a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarText" aria-controls="navbarText" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```